# Help understanding products of permutation cycles.

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, permutation-cycles

In Thomas Hungerford's "*Abstract Algebra - An Introduction*" he is giving following examples of products of cycles of permutations:

- $(567)^2=(576)$
- $(1234)=(12)(23)(34)$
- $(1243)(243)=(23)(34)(14)$

What I see in the first line is that in $(567)(567)$, the first cycle sends $5$ to $6$, and the second cycle sends $6$ to $7$, so that the result of the product is $5\rightarrow 7$ (and similarly we get $6\rightarrow 5$ and $7\rightarrow 6$. But if that is true, then it looks like the $3$ cycles on the right side of line $2$ sends $1\rightarrow2$, $2\rightarrow 3$ and $3\rightarrow 4$, so that the product would give $1\rightarrow 4$ and not $1\rightarrow 2$? Another doubt I have is that it seems that on the third line, $3$ is sent to two different numbers. Can someone help me understand how these products work?

Comment: Composition is being done right-to-left: so $(12)(23)(34)$ means you apply $(34)$ *first*, then $(23)$, then $(12)$ (think of them as functions being applied to the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$). So $1$ is fixed by $(34$, fixed by $(23)$, then sent to $2$. $2$ is fixed by $(34)$, sent to $3$ by $(23)$, and then $3$ is fixed by $(12)$, etc.

Comment: The third one neither side is a product of disjoint cycles. On the left side, $(1243)(243)$, $1$ is sent to $2$; then $2\to4\to 3$, then $3\to 2\to 4$, then $4\to3\to1$. So you get $(1234)$. On the right, $1\to4\to3\to2$, $2\to3$, $3\to 4$, and $4\to1$. So both are $(1234)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, but if composition is done right-to-left, in $(1243)(243)$, why do we not have, for example, $2\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 1$?

Comment: Because you don't apply $(1243)$ *twice*. What happens to $2$ when you apply $(243)$? It goes to $4$. And what happens to $4$ when you apply $(1243)$? It goes to $3$. So after appying the product $(1243)(243)$ to $2$, it ends up in $3$. Next, what happens to $3$? $(243)$ sends it to $2$, and then $2$ is sent to $4$ by $(1243)$. So in total, $(1243(243)$ sends $3$ to $4$. Etc.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, thank you, I understand it now.

Comment: Some sources do permutation composition the other way (left-to-right). So be sure to check when looking at a different source.